# Form xml element from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I want to convert the sql table records into below xml format. Can you please give your suggestions in it.

SQL Server table:

```
id  name
-------------
1   Arun
2   Raghavan
```

I want to form the xml elements from the above table like the below format in a SQL query

```
<row>
    <Field Name="Customer.id" Value="id">
    <Field Name="Customer.name" Value="arun">
</row>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like

```
SELECT 'Customer.id' AS [@Name]
      ,id AS [@Value]
FROM SomeTable
FOR XML PATH('Field'),ROOT('row');
```

If you really need this with the table's and the column's name concatenated like in your example, there is no *easy-going*. In this case [John Cappelletti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43394540/5089204) is great!

But check these *out-of-the-box* approaches (`AUTO` will generate the table's name as element's name):

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (id int,name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES
 (1,'Arun')
,(2,'Raghavan');

SELECT * FROM SomeTable FOR XML AUTO;
SELECT * FROM SomeTable FOR XML RAW;
```

--Result for first

```
<SomeTable id="1" name="Arun" />
<SomeTable id="2" name="Raghavan" />
```

--Result for second

```
<row id="1" name="Arun" />
<row id="2" name="Raghavan" />
```

Comment: I dont want to mention the column name. Because table can vary based on my need. I want column name and field values needs to filled automatically in sql query

Answer (score 1):

This is where my thinking takes me.

This is a dynamic unpivot which is then converted back into a consolidated XML object.

I added **Cross Apply C** to hold the table name, but this can be a variable.

```
Declare @YourTable table (id int,name varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'Arun'),
(2,'Raghavan')

Select D.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml) ) B
 Cross Apply (Select TableName='Customer') C
 Cross Apply (
                Select row = (
                                Select [@Name]   = C.TableName+'.'+attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                                      ,[@Value]  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                                 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                                 For XML Path('Field'),Type
                              )
            ) D
 For XML Path(''),Type
```

**Returns**

```
<row>
  <Field Name="Customer.id" Value="1" />
  <Field Name="Customer.name" Value="Arun" />
</row>
<row>
  <Field Name="Customer.id" Value="2" />
  <Field Name="Customer.name" Value="Raghavan" />
</row>
```

Comment: Great, I updated my answer to point to `FOR XML AUTO`... This approach is a good solution, but quite a hack :-D

Comment: @Shnugo Been called far worse ... this morning   :)

Comment: Hi @John, I just placed another answer. Think, you'll like it :-D

Comment: @Shnugo I have no doubt.  I'll take a peek when I'm back in my office.

Answer (score 1):

I place this as a second answer, as the approach is so completely different:

First I use [`SELECT ... FOR XML AUTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-auto-mode-with-for-xml). This will create simple tags, where the table's name is the element's name and all fields are generated as attributes.

From this I continue with a [FLWOR XQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/flwor-statement-and-iteration-xquery). First I read all nodes, then all attributes within the nodes. This is re-generated as the XML needed:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (id int,name varchar(50))
INSERT INTO SomeTable VALUES
 (1,'Arun')
,(2,'Raghavan');
```

--The query (you can place any table's, view's or TVF's name instead of "SomeTable")

```
SELECT
(
SELECT * FROM SomeTable FOR XML AUTO,TYPE  --<-- Here is the simple SELECT
).query('
         for $nd in /*
         return <row>
         {
             for $attr in $nd/@*
             return <Field Name="{concat(local-name($nd),".",local-name($attr))}" Value="{$attr}"/>
         }
         </row>');
GO
--Clean up (careful with real data!)
--DROP TABLE SomeTable;
GO
```

The result

```
<row>
  <Field Name="SomeTable.id" Value="1" />
  <Field Name="SomeTable.name" Value="Arun" />
</row>
<row>
  <Field Name="SomeTable.id" Value="2" />
  <Field Name="SomeTable.name" Value="Raghavan" />
</row>
```

Comment: Most impressive.  Covers OP's requirements with less code and faster  ... 23% faster.  No idea how it works yet